# Problema con blockUI JS , no funciona unblockUI() Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-ui

Estoy utilizando el plugin blockUI js, pero no funciona correctamente en peticiones por ajax. El problema es que cuando realizó un busqueda, el cargador de pagina aparece pero no se desaparece aunq los resultados de la busqueda se muestren, el cargador sigue pegado.

Aquí dejo el código de ajax.

```
 function buscarVuelosAjax()

{

var fchDespegueAjax =$("#fechaDespegueAjax").val();
var fchArriboAjax =$("#fechaArriboAjax").val();

$.ajax({
url:"buscarVuelosAjax.do",
data:{
fdespegue : fchDespegueAjax,
farribo:fchArriboAjax
},
beforeSend: function() {
$.blockUI({ css: {
border: 'none', 
padding: '15px', 
backgroundColor: '#000', 
'-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
'-moz-border-radius': '10px',
 opacity: .5, 
color: '#fff'
} }); 
 },

success: function( result ) {
$( "#resultadoVuelo" ).html( result);
 },
complete: function() {
$.unblockUI();
},
});
}
```

Acá imagen de como se ve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estimados me podrían ayudar por favor, hice un debug a mi aplicación pero me dice que no hay errores, entonces no se que puede ser lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Hola buenas , cual podría ser el problema?